# Stop Model Builder from resetting field maps when changing input

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, spatial-join, field-mapping

ArcGIS Pro 3.0.2

I am doing a `Spatial Join` in Model Builder and set the input as a parameter. I then use the `Field Map` settings to change the field names and merge rules. This works fine when I run / validate it from the Edit view.

However, if I change the input feature class, then the `Field Maps` I set before get dropped and it resets to the default merge rules.

Is there a way to stop this from happening? It seems like having to edit the Field Maps every time I run it defeats the purpose of a model.

Comment: It's a bug in ArcPro 3.0.2, I've logged it as case with ESRI UK. Apparently they fired it off to Redlands who replied saying it was "by design", which is nonsense and they have clearly not understood the implication of this behaviour in models such as yours. Until someone in ESRI up the change of command understands and accepts the issue, we can't do anything about it, lets hope its been fixed in 3.1....

Comment: My current solution is to make a copy of the input files to a constant workspace and file name. This isn't a complete fix as I can't change the workspace, but at least I can change the input files without resetting the field map. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi8el.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi8el.png) I contacted ESRI Support and was told this behaviour is as expected. They were not able to provide any "out of the box" solutions or work-arounds, but suggested I try the script in this article: https://community.esri.com/t5/geoprocessing-questions/spatial-join-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**11/2/2022**

According to Hornbydd, seems to be bug, how unfortunate.

In the meantime, I figured workaround is to temporarily rename my feature class before the spatial join, then rename it back to the original name at the very end of my model using an expression.

---

[image: screen shot rename tool]

- `Rename` tool to something constant like `temp`. Since the input Feature Class name for the tool is now constant, the tool keeps my Field Map settings.

[image: screen shot with calculate name]

- Then rename it back to the original with a `Calculate Value` expression from the `Utilities` drop down.

Comment: Sneaky....Nice one!